# Creating a raw HTTP request through a specific port

Tags: c, http, curl, libcurl

I want to create a HTTP request from a specific port using C on a Linux machine.  There is `libcurl` but I'm not sure if you can specify the interface.  Is it possible ?

Many thanks :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. Look into the options [`CURLOPT_INTERFACE`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTINTERFACE) and [`CURLOPT_LOCALPORT`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTLOCALPORT).

Comment: Thanks very much.. I should have spotted that.